# Car sound with respect to speed?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, audio, soundeffect

I need my car sound pitch to be changed with respect to speed.
Current I am using the solution of an answer which is :https://answers.unity.com/questions/1067016/car-engine-sound-code-unity5car-engine-sound-code.html

```
public float topSpeed = 100; // km per hour
private float currentSpeed = 0;
private float pitch = 0;

void Update () 
{
     currentSpeed = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 3.6f;
     pitch = currentSpeed / topSpeed;

     transform.GetComponent <AudioSource> ().Pitch = pitch;
}
```

As per this the starting `pitch` is `0` 
And it changes as per my `currentSpeed` 
I.e - `currentSpeed`/`topSpeed` so when my current `speed = topSpeed` the `pitch` will be `1` and it's good approach 
But in my case it plays the sound but when once my car reaches `topSpeed` it stops playing sound than and never plays it again even if I brake and start from zero speed

As I am an beginner intermediate I think it's because of my rigidbody of car is kinematic but I don't know the correct reason and any solution of this.

Comment: Does the pitch reduce when your Current speed is within your Top Speed limit?

Comment: Does your pitch variable ever decrease,  when your current speed is within your Top Speed limit?

Comment: No it does'nt reduce when on top speed but when i reduce the speed it reduces but dont play any sound

Comment: Have you tried transform. Get Component<AudioSource>(). Pitch =0.5 + (currentSpeed/topSpeed)

Answer (score 1):

İ know it's too late to answer it. But maybe it helps for other people who have same issue.

this is the simplest way you can do with one sound,

type this to Vehicle controller script

```
 //Vehicle's rigidbody
 Rigidbody _rigidBody;
  
 //You have to assign in a sound
 public AudioSource _shipSound;
 float EngineAcceleration = 10f;

 private void Start()
 {
    _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
    _SoundShip.Play();  
 }
 private void Update()
 {
   //simply we divide Rigidbody speed to ourAcceleration
  _SoundShip.pitch = Mathf.Clamp(_rigidBody.velocity.magnitude / 
  EngineAcceleration , 
  minEngineSound, maxEngineSound);
 }
```